# Textbox transition doesn't work, what may be causing it?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
.search-query
{
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    -moz-transition: width 2s;
    -o-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s;
}

.search-query:hover
{
    width: 500px;
}

<form action="" class="navbar-search pull-right">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-query" />
</form>
```

I expect textbox to grow from 300px to 500px in `two seconds`, but it grows `instantly`.
I'm pretty new to CSS transitions so I can't figure it out myself. However, it looks exactly the same as the `example on w3schools.com` and it works there.

What's the problem?

**Update:** The example above works in jsfiddle, it's probably related to my layout so here is the whole layout using Twitter Bootstrap.

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner navbar-fixed-top">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Project Name</a>

        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
        </ul>

        <form action="" class="navbar-search pull-right">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-query" />
            <input type="submit" id="search-submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-small" value="Search">
        </form>

        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Ps. I'm on FF 20.0.1

Comment: Works fine for me in FF 20.0.1 .. can you replicate the issue with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Adrift; Your example works for me too. I've updated my question and included the whole layout. (Using bootstrap.) I can't figure it out. It has more than enough free area to resize correctly.

Comment: Can you put all the relevant code within a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/zfCKH/1/ Included all the necessary libraries. Your solution on the answer works but I don't know why it is working to be honest. `.search-query` is correctly pointing to the textbox since it grows on size with the hover method, just the transition doesn't work. Why do I need to be more specific with my selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on line 1116 of bootstrap.css you already have a `transition` applying to the input with a more specific selector, so try including ancestor classes to outweigh the specificity, e.g.

```
.navbar .navbar-inner .navbar-search .search-query
{
width: 300px;
-webkit-transition: width 2s;
-moz-transition: width 2s;
-o-transition: width 2s;
 transition: width 2s;
}

.navbar .navbar-inner .navbar-search .search-query:hover
{
width: 500px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zfCKH/2/)

Comment: It's strange. At first I thought about it, but didn't bothered to try since textbox was successfully resizing to 500px without transition effects. Your solution works for me and solved my issue, but what exactly is that happening? I mean, both search-query and div.div.search-query points to the same textbox.

Comment: Its because the `<input>` already has another transition applying to it on line 1116 in `bootstrap.css` and the selector is more specific